# Rails keeps flash when clicking link in flash message (it shouldn't)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

#### Note: This is different from the now vs notice issue. Please read on.

I have a link in a flash notice that gets displayed correctly after the redirect. However, **when I click the link, which is to a different controller action that simply renders a view, the notice containing the link persists in that page**. This is usually how it works in that the notice only disappears if its a redirect, so I guess the question is how to make the link behave as a redirect? I am not entirely sure.

Some code to illustrate:

`redirect_to root_url, notice: "I am a notice with a #{link}"`

And `link` is simply a route to an action that does not thing but render a layout, so its effectively:

`def action
 end`

Now, the above code is fine, but when I click on that link in the notice, the same notice will persist in that link's page, which is not the desired behavior here. Any idea how to deal with this? In other words, we are looking for a way to make the link in the notice not carry the notice around with it.

#### EDITS (2)

I tried the flash.now trick. It will not work since the next method call is a redirect, which defeats the whole purpose of flash.now

Comment: Show us the code for the action where the notice is first set, and the action that's relevant to the link.

Comment: Hey @MikeCampbell the notice is set in the code I showed above, minus some html formatting for the link and such, which is not relevant. I will add the other action of the link.

Comment: This is certainly non-standard behaviour, must be something odd with what you are doing. Are you about to replicate it in a fresh Rails app?

Comment: Yes, I will most likely.

Comment: On rails-app here it's done with `- if flash[:notice]` in the view and then some haml code. I'm kinda guessing your issue has to do with something else. Well, just throwing it out there anyways, maybe you come up with an idea xD

Comment: Mind showing us the rendered link on the first page? Also try visiting the second page directly in address bar and see if the notice is still there.

Comment: There really just isn't enough context here to help. Could we have the code for the action generating the flash message and the code for the action that the user is redirected to?

Comment: When you click the link, are you initiating a GET or a POST?

Comment: What I really mean to ask is, What value is in `link`?

Comment: Is it possible that any middleware is calling `flash.keep`?

Comment: Hey Isaac, the link is a get to a normal rails action that does nothing but render its corresponding view. I will investigate the middleware now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
flash.now[:notice] = "I am a notice with a #{link_to_another_controller_action}"
redirect_to root_url
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code accordingly it will work

There are two ways of displaying flash message feature

Instantly on the same page load, and accessible in the view from `flash['foo']:`

```
flash.now['foo'] = "Hello world"
```

Or on a redirect to another page, and accessible from `flash['notice']:`

```
redirect_to root_url, notice: "Hello world"
```

ROR gudies website is a good reference:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

Answer (score 0):

Then try the [discard](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-discard) method. In your case, it should probably take a form like this in the target controller action:

```
flash.discard
flash.discard(:notice)
```

Comment: I know this option, and I don't like it, since it means that I am discarding all notices on target action, and that is a code smell. I could disregard conditionally based on the referrer, but that is still a very bad way of doing it since I am offloading the problem to an otherwise unrelated action.